# Power BI - Regional setting Dax Separators

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have installed Power BI on my personnal PC and also on my company PC and on my personall PC I can go to settings Regional Settings and choose the DAX Separators but on my work PC I dont have that option, can anyone help me ? I have download it from the Microsoft Store.
The image below what is in the red square doesnt show up my company PC.

[image]